# Microsoft Graph API- no way to retrieve available Office 365 supported services for domains

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Goal: Automate Office 365 domain verification and DNS service record retrieval. Retrieve a list of supported Microsoft services for verified domains.

---

Solution: Retrieve DNS records using

```
GET /domains/contoso.com/serviceConfigurationRecords
```

and configure the domain.

---

Issue: When a domain is added to a tenant and verified, none of the DNS records can be retrieved via Graph because the domain does not *support any services* (although, the admin portal UI does display the service DNS records immediately following domain verification). To update *supported services* for a domain, I need to know **which ones can be supported**.

---

Question:

- Is there a way to retrieve the list of all available services which I can use to patch the domain?
- Can I patch the domain in a way which will automatically set it to support all the available services?
- Any other idea?